AWS Private CA shared with another account via AWS RAM not available for selection in the target service (ECS)
For reference, I used this guide on sharing my Private CA, which leverages AWS Resource Access Manager (RAM):
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/acm-share-pca-with-another-account
I have successfully shared the Private CA and can see it in the other account, however, when I go to the service I want to use it with (ECS), I do not see it in drop down for Service Connect. It shows up perfectly fine in the primary account that it is being shared from.
I have opened a case with AWS, however, they are still reviewing but the support agent did confirm they are able to replicate the issue. Has anyone else experienced this and found a workaround?
Here is the ECS UI where I expect to see it:
ECS Service Connect config missing shared PCA
Here is the Private CA dashboard where I can see that it's shared from the primary account:
Account B showing the shared PCA
